# JQuery Mobile : having a background image of a button stretching

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have an image used as a background for a login button. I'd like that, when the size of the button is changed, the image is stretched to continue to fill the button. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks by advance.

Here's the CSS code of the button :

```
.Submit{width : 25% !important; background-image:       url("/intranet_mob/images/login.png")
```

And the HTML code of the button :

```
<button type="submit" class="Submit"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the css property `background-size:100% 100%;`

**Demo** wait 5secs to see the change;

https://jsfiddle.net/dz4d52tg/

**Css**

```
#btn {
width:100px;
background: url("http://s30.postimg.org/i4ikqcy59/demo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

More Information here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=50%25